# MVC post not getting the updated value of a mvc textbox, when we change the content of a txtbox via jquery in client side which is copied from a pup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-view-controller

We have a MVC textbox(orignal textbox) in our form that expects time formatted string(eg:10:30), and we have provided a normal button next to it that opens a pop-up and user can see another textbox inside that which can be used for entering time in decimal format(eg:10.5) 
then the pop-up shows the converted decimal to time format ie; 10:30. If user clicks OK then we takes the accepted value from the popup to orignal text box in the form.

The above user actions are done via jquery, we shows up jquery poupup and normal html input text box and takes the value back to original ASP.net MVC text box control.

All is fine, even jquery works fine. we have even checked the value of the original text box in javascript from DOM in Developer tool, But the value property of the original text is still the old value what we received when we opened our form - but when we checked the value using javascript in developer tool watch- its our new value.
Looks like our update in the value on the textbox is not posting to server.

Do anyone have any idea to make this working?

Comment: can you post the code - HTML of the 'original textbox' and script to modify this text box with formatted value?